# Unsure about dream and spoke about it

Tags: practical-islam, dream, lying

So my aunt and I were sitting. She told me that she has seen her mother (my grandmother in dream). I said I have also seen my her in my dream.

Now the thing is that I distantly remember that I saw my grandmother in dream. But I was unsure since remembering dreams is not an easy task.
However as soon as she said that she saw my grandmother in dream, it immediately triggered that I have seen my grandmother in dream and I also then slightly recalled the dream and I spoke that I also saw her in my dream.

I'm not sure that I saw her in my dream or did it all come out on its own

Does it fall in the lies of dream?
Because there is strict Hadith about lying about dreams.

I'm worried.

Comment: you yourself should decide if you have seen something or not.

Comment: But I was unsure

Comment: Does it fall under lying about the dream?

Comment: I do not know. anyway do tawbah and in future have caution